# Using all dataframe entries after second column in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i want to look for the max value of a dataframe in python.

```
csv_data['Numbers'] = csv_data[["Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4", "Column 5"]].max(1)
```

the csv has in the first 2 entries Words. So i want to select alle entries AFTER the words without writing everything manually. something like this:

```
csv_data['Numbers'] = csv_data["everything after 2"].max(1)
```

do you have an idea?

Sincerely Pascal

Comment: Can you add an example of the data to clarify? And the matching expected output. Do you just want `csv_data.iloc[:, 2:].max(1)`?

Comment: thank you. this is what im looking for. 
i had a csv looking like this:
Name;Parts;Variable1;Variable2;Variable3;Variable4;Variable5
Name;PartNr;0;1;2;1;0
Name2;PartNr2;0;1;0;2
...
Output should be
csv_data["Name","Parts","Numbers"]
Displaying the Name, partNr and the highest Nr

Comment: please [edit] the question, comments are not good for data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @mozway, iloc can be used select columns

```
csv_data['Numbers'] = csv_data.iloc[:,2:].max(1)
```

You can also set numeric_only to get the max of numeric values

```
csv_data['num'] = csv_data.max(axis =1,numeric_only=True)
```